# migration orbeon to 4.9 from 3.7.1

Tags: orbeon

I am updating orbeon from 3.7.1 to the newest 4.9.
Seems widget is not used in 4.9. How can I migration our widget logic to the 4.9. Could you provide some detail steps for me.

Also we create some processor in 3.7.1. But there is lots of errors when I use the jars in 4.9 to build. Some methods are removed in 4.9, like `readInputAsDOM(PipelineContext context, String inputName)`. Does any other method I can use to replace it.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "widget"? About you customer processor, you'll need to recompile the code and make changes as appropriate to get it to compile against the new API. Specifically about `readInputAsDOM`, it is still a public method on [`ProcessorImpl`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/processor/ProcessorImpl.java). I can't answer that question more precisely not knowing on which object you're calling that method, but you can hopefully figure it out looking at the latest code.

Comment: in 3.7.1. you have a xforms-widgets.xsl. I can include my widget by using following <xsl:include href="../core/widgets/all-widgets.xsl"/>. But in 4.9.0. I can't find any widget information now. How Can I include my all-widgets.xsl? Thanks.

Comment: I see, I completely forgot about this xforms-widgets.xsl; it's been gone for quite a while now! That was a way to implement components that started before we had XBL. For instance, we had an implementation of tabs in https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/tag-release-dev-3.7.1/src/resources/config/xforms-widgets.xsl.

Comment: Now, that was just some XSLT running before the XForms engine. You could achieve the same result in 4.9 by running a preprocessing step: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/XForms-~-Configuration-Properties#preprocessing-step. You'd have to create an XPL that runs your XSLT. This is most likely the quickest way to get your code to run on 4.9. If you have a bit more time though, I'd recommend you create an XBL component instead of relying on XSLT for this.

Comment: we used the validate-request in 3.7.1. 
            <!--validate the request -->
            <p:processor name="oxf:validate-request">
                <p:output name="data" id="validate-referer-result"/>
            </p:processor>
But now error throw when run the validate:Cannot find processor factory with name "{http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors}validate-request" which validate function I can used to validate the request in 4.9

Comment: Not sure: I don't even see a `oxf:validate-request` processor in the 3.7.1 code [here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/tag-release-dev-3.7.1/src/resources-packaged/processors.xml). But this certainly seems to be gone from the product.

Comment: Following errors printer to the console. I check the orbeon.jar. The dateUtils exists in. Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.orbeon.oxf.util.DateUtils$
        at org.orbeon.oxf.util.DateUtils.parseRFC1123(DateUtils.scala)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.util.NetUtils.checkIfModifiedSince(NetUtils.java:87)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.ServletExternalContext$Response.checkIfModifiedSince(ServletExternalContext.java:565)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsResourceServer.serveCSSOrJavaScript(XFormsResourceServer.scala:162)

Comment: And the  DateUtils.parseRFC1123(ifModifiedHeader); in line 92. not 87. in NetUtils.java   Am I loss anything?

Comment: Another error in the console. I don't know why this print.                             ]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl$ProcessorOutputImpl: method <init>(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang
/String;)V not found
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.CacheProcessor$1.<init>(CacheProcessor.java:50)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.CacheProcessor.createOutput(CacheProcessor.java:50)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.createConfigFromAST(PipelineProcessor.java:228)

Comment: `DateUtils` is definitely present in the code and in use. So I don't know why you are getting these errors. Could it be a corrupted JAR, or duplicate JAR, like Joda-Time?